# Python selenium explicit wait error

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I got the below working a few days ago but it no longer seems to be working for me anymore i am now getting an error that reads:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'XPATH'
```

Any ideas what is wrong with the code?

```
try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)
    element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,("/html/body/div[9]/div[1]/div[3]/div/ul/li[1]/div/div[3]/span[1]/a"))))
finally:
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div[1]/div[3]/div/ul/li[1]/div/div[3]/span[1]/a").click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print "NO New Video"
        pass
```

Comment: did you update the browser you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you've upgraded your version of Selenium. Before XPATH was defined in the module's namespace. Now (in version 2.44.0), it is an attribute in the `By` class:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, 
     "/html/body/div[9]/div[1]/div[3]/div/ul/li[1]/div/div[3]/span[1]/a")))
```